# Not able to read variable from .env file in under when call login service

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

I am trying to calling .env variable using process.env .But I am not able to at the time of calling login service.I have define Host variable and calling that variable under login service .ex:-

> XHR({ url : https://${process.env.host}/../}

Please provide your suggestion.env file will have value like `H_HOST= XYX`

```
abc.model.login = function (callback) {
  XHR{(
    url: `https:\\$(process.env.H_HOST)\Dir1\dir2`,
    responseType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {..},
    body: ..,
  )}
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code samples :)

Comment: @jugal If you're using a .env file, are you requiring the `dotenv` module and setting the correct path in the config?

Comment: Yes I am doing that

Comment: I don't know the details but, why not use like this 'https:\\' + process.env.H_HOST+ '\Dir1\dir2' ?